# Action Filter for non MVC Web Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, action-filter

I was searching for a solution to validate query string parameters and redirect the client to a specific page in case of an invalid query string parameter. I have found a solution wih action filters.

But my project is not an MVC project. I would like to ask :

What can I use for a non MVC project that will behave like an action filter.

Or any other kind of recommendation is also appreciated.

Thanx

Comment: You are looking for HttpModule

Comment: You can try with using jQuery.